# Django Postgres Replace Function

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I want to find all strings, but discard unwanted characters.

I have the following rows:

```
test!

t!est

!t!e!st!

aaa!
```

I want to find all `test`(but remove all unwanted characters).
From above table I want to get

```
test!

t!est

!t!e!st!
```

`Table.objects.filter(name=test_or_test_with some_unwanted_symbols)`.

I don't know how to apply Django `F` and `Func` here.

Comment: What does "Postgers" in the title mean?

Comment: Postgres database.

Comment: You could have corrected that in the title.

Comment: Corrected. Do you know a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know a solution. But I was wondering what has Postgres to do with the question. It won't help neither yourself, nor other users if the questions are not properly titled and tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Django `Replace` function (introduced in Django 2.1) [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#replace).

For your example, you would want to use it in an annotation:

```py
>>> from django.db.models import Value
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Replace
>>>
>>> Thing.objects.create(name='test!')
>>> Thing.objects.create(name='t!est')
>>> Thing.objects.create(name='!t!e!st!')
>>> Thing.objects.create(name='aaa!')
>>>
>>> things = thing.objects.annotate(
>>>     clean_name=Replace('name', Value('!'), Value(''))
>>> )
>>> things.filter(clean_name='test').values("name")
<QuerySet [{'name': 'test!'}, {'name': 't!est'}, {'name': '!t!e!st!'}]>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) over here

```
import re
a=['test!','t!est','!t!e!st!','aaa!']
for i in a:
    k=re.sub(r"\W", "", i)
    if 'test' in k:
        print (k)
```

Comment: How will this help me to fetch results from database?

Comment: You'll have to fetch all entries from the database first and after that filter only those you need.

Comment: `a` should be a list, but it hase curly braces, like a dictionary. Can you please correct that?

Comment: @cezar corrected. Whoever downvoted the answer, please explain the reason?